# After moving BluetoothActivity into service class.How to send data to service from another activity to control led

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I'm using service to run Bluetooth in background,but i don't no how to send data from another activity to service

Answer (score 0):

- Service and other activities work in the same process

To start a Service, use following statement:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Service.class);
// intent put some extra
startService(intent);
```

Calling this statement firstly, Service call `onCreate()` method and `onStartCommand()`.

Not firstly, Service just call `onStartCommand()`.

You can check if it is called firstly by extra in intent.

So you can send data with the same method `startService(Intent intent)`.

- Service works in another process

use [bindService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)) and [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

It is suggested that make service and other activities work in the same process when your target is not complex.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.